# Google App Engine static css and js files

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I want to create a Google App Engine hosted application on http://hangoutsangular.appspot.com/

Unfortunately my scripts and css files are not delivered, instead the request hits my index.html file as well.

Here is the content of my app.yaml file:

```
handlers:
- url: /css
static_dir: css
- url: /js
static_dir: js
- url: /.*
script: index.html
```

What's wrong regarding my configuration?

Comment: Do you have the directories 'css' and 'js' in your apps root?

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue. The configuration is correct. I changed Version in app.yaml from 1 to 2. Due to this my update-procedures where accessible through a new domain.